# Using sharekit to check for a successful facebook post

Tags: sharekit

I have implemented sharekit so I can post using facebook on my iPad. I would like to set a flag upon a successful facebook post...what is the best way of doing this using sharekit and any examples of what Code I should put in my files would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check for shareKit's notifications, namely SHKSendDidFinishNotification